# Why does the search functionality stop working for the encrypted PDFs?

Tags: catalina, pdf, preview, encryption

The search functionality simply does not work for the encrypted PDFs. The original PDF is searchable. When I encrypt it (to let access through password), the search function does not work for this encrypted PDF. What could be the reason behind this odd situation?

p.s. I'm on the latest available version of `Catalina` - `10.15.4`. And, I used the `Preview` app to encrypt the PDF file.

Comment: Which search functionality are you talking about: Spotlight or inside Preview? Was searching working before Catalina?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I meant inside the Preview app. No idea as I have not encrypted any PDFs before on macOS. @nohillside

Comment: I only have Mojave, here the PDF remains searchable. Let's see what others come up with.